# Add calculated data from userform

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

I have a working userform ui in google spreadsheet that works just fine. It adds 1 row of data I enter in userform. But I need to add more rows with changed data.

For example the second row added, I need this div id "incomeeur" to be multiplied by a percentage number that is located in sheet2 of the same spreadsheet file in the H6 cell.
The third row added, "incomeeur" multiplied by a different percentage number in sheet2 H7 cell.
[image: example of 2 additinal rows]

But I don't know how to take the value from this "incomeeur" and multiply it by the cell in sheet2.
I tried to do something like this, but it never worked, so I just deleted that from the code.

```
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet2');
  const incomeeur3 = ws.getRange('H6').getValue();
  const incomeeur2 = document.getElementById("incomeeur").getValue();
  const incomeeur4 = incomeeur2 * incomeeur3;
```

Can anyone help? :)

So far I have 2 files:

1. HTML

   ```html
   <!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">

   <body>

   <div class="container">
   <div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="docnumber">№ doc</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="docnumber" 
   placeholder="Вул./місто/клієнт/виріб">
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="whereandhow">sender</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="whereandhow">
   </select>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="comment">comment</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comment" placeholder="Введіть примітку">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="incomeeur">income, €</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="incomeeur" placeholder="Cума, €">
   </div>

   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="mainButton">Додати</button>
   </div>
   </div>

   <script>

     function afterButtonClicked(){
     var docnumber1 = document.getElementById("docnumber");
     var whereandhow1 = document.getElementById("whereandhow");
     var comment1 = document.getElementById("comment");
     var incomeeur1 = document.getElementById("incomeeur");
     var incomeusd1 = document.getElementById("incomeusd");
     var incomeuah1 = document.getElementById("incomeuah");
     var eurrate1 = document.getElementById("eurrate");
     var usdrate1 = document.getElementById("usdrate");
     var expenseeur1 = document.getElementById("expenseeur");
     var expenseusd1 = document.getElementById("expenseusd");
     var expenseuah1 = document.getElementById("expenseuah");
     var expensetype1 = document.getElementById("expensetype");

     var rowData = {docnumber1: docnumber1.value,whereandhow1: whereandhow1.value,comment1: comment1.value,incomeeur4: incomeeur4.value,incomeusd1: incomeusd1.value,incomeuah1: incomeuah1.value,eurrate1: eurrate1.value,usdrate1: usdrate1.value,expenseeur1: expenseeur1.value,expenseusd1: expenseusd1.value,expenseuah1: expenseuah1.value,expensetype1: expensetype1.value};
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterSubmit).addNewRow(rowData)
     }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
   ```
2. Then in gs file, I run function for data entry into the spreadsheet

```js
function addNewRow(rowData) {

    const currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "dd.MM.yy");
    
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const ws = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');
    ws.appendRow([currentDate,rowData.docnumber1,rowData.whereandhow1,rowData.comment1,rowData.incomeeur4,rowData.incomeusd1,rowData.incomeuah1,rowData.eurrate1,rowData.usdrate1,rowData.expenseeur1,rowData.expenseusd1,rowData.expenseuah1,rowData.expensetype1]);

return true;

}
```

all credits go to this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzUDw7O8yhE&list=PLv9Pf9aNgemuzTNWeHd8HziGVNzSlWACh&index=2

Comment: Why do you define the variable as `var incomeeur1 = ...` but then pass the nowhere defined variable as `incomeeur4: incomeeur4.value`? Is it a typo? As for the rest, if I understand you right, all you need is just to modify the cell in the last new row AFTER the row is pasted. But I not quite grasp the logic. Do you mean when the new row has index `7959` it should take percents from the cell `Sheet2:H7959`?

Comment: допомоги від росіян не потрібно! russian assistance is not needed!

Comment: Bohdan, my grandfather from Odessa. Slava Ukraine.  It's not my fault I was born in Moscow. I hope Putin's Russia will fall soon.

Comment: And I will be glad to help you. It's least I can do right now. I can't kill Putin.